# Free access to the OED in the Americas (13-19 April 2014)

Tags: discussion

This is more of an announcement than discussion but [this](http://global.oup.com/academic/librarians/national-library-week//) may be useful for people here [ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/free-access-to-the-oed-in-the-americas-13-19-april-2014):

> **National Library Week**
>
> ***All OUP Online products are free April 13-19th***
>
> To celebrate National Library Week in the United States (April 13th-19th) and all the hard work librarians do to support their patrons, OUP is freeing up all of our online products* for the week! Libraries are a vital part of many communities, whether it is a school, a town/city, the government, a corporation, or a hospital, and we have freed up this unprecedented amount of content to show our appreciation for these libraries.
>
> Simply use the below login credentials!
> No sign-ups are required!
>
> Username: libraryweek
> Password: libraryweek

Comment: Hooray for libraries!

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm it's working here in India too!

Comment: Thanks! It works in Iran too!! :))

Comment: Works here in Finland too!

Comment: Works here on Mars, too.

Comment: Aaaah! Missed it!

Comment: Updated for 2014!

Comment: Copy all the pages into questions for the site!

Comment: @Oldcat: I don't think that free *access* implies waiver of copyright.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a past event.